# Travelling to Pakistan with expired NICOP

Tags: dual-nationality, pakistan

According to the Federal Immigration Authority Pakistan, it's possible for dual citizens to travel to Pakistan with an expired NICOP.

http://www.fia.gov.pk/en/achievements/broucher/EN.jpg

I've already booked my ticket with PIA. Anyone here who has traveled under similar circumstances? I just want to be sure that I will be allowed to board.

Comment: Did they let you go with an expired NICOP? My cousin’s planning to come and his NICOP is expired

Comment: As long as the NICOP is the digital one, you should not have any issues. The older NICOP holders will also not have issues, but may face delays at immigration as these need to be validated separately.

Comment: I just talk to PAK consulate Houston. They told me its its not true. U cant travel on expired NICOP.

Comment: Can someone please tell me if they had travel on expired NICOP? I don’t know who to believe? PAK Consulate or FIA brouchore?

Answer (score 2):

You should be allowed to board, as NICOP is an official identification document, a visa, for Pakistani citizens living and/or working abroad. A test search through Timatic, the database used by airlines to check passenger document requirements, indicated that boarding would be permitted if a passenger holds a certificate of citizenship for Pakistan.

That said, it would be wise to carry with you a printed copy of the [FIA Ministry of the Interior brochure](http://www.fia.gov.pk/en/achievements/broucher/EN.jpg) which states that you would be allowed to enter even if the NICOP has expired.

Should you have sufficient time before departure, you may want to contact the nearest [Pakistan Mission](http://www.mofa.gov.pk/content.php?pageID=missions), or [begin the renewal process online](https://id.nadra.gov.pk/renew-id/).

Comment: You don't need to print any brochures.